# I am trying to make the background image a auto slider

Tags: html, css

Right now I only add one image I want to add multiple images want to make them rotate, I tried everything I have learned but I fail.Please help

This is my code

```
.home {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 9rem;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7)), to(rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7))), url(../images/home-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7), rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7)), url(../images/home-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
.sliding-background {
  background: url("path to the image") repeat-x;
  height: 500px;
  width: 5076px;
}

@keyframes .slide {
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
  }
}
.sliding-background {
  background: url("..path/to/image") repeat-x;
  height: 560px;
  width: 5076px;
  animation: slide 60s linear infinite;
}
```